# How can I raise an exception through Tornado coroutines incorrectly called?

Tags: python, python-2.7, asynchronous, tornado

I have a scenario with Tornado where I have a coroutine that is called from a non-coroutine or without yielding, yet I need to propagate the exception back.

Imagine the following methods:

```
@gen.coroutine
def create_exception(with_yield):
    if with_yield:
        yield exception_coroutine()
    else:
        exception_coroutine()

@gen.coroutine
def exception_coroutine():
    raise RuntimeError('boom')

def no_coroutine_create_exception(with_yield):
    if with_yield:
        yield create_exception(with_yield)
    else:
        create_exception(with_yield)
```

Calling:

```
try:
    # Throws exception
    yield create_exception(True)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

will properly raise the exception. However, none of the following raise the exception :

```
try:
    # none of these throw the exception at this level
    yield create_exception(False)
    no_coroutine_create_exception(True)
    no_coroutine_create_exception(False)
except Exception as e:
    print('This is never hit)
```

The latter are variants similar to what my problem is - I have code outside my control calling coroutines without using yield. In some cases, they are not coroutines themselves. Regardless of which scenario, it means that any exceptions they generate are swallowed until Tornado returns them as "future exception not received."

This is pretty contrary to Tornado's intent, their documentation basically states you need to do yield/coroutine through the entire stack in order for it to work as I'm desiring without hackery/trickery.

I can change the way the exception is raised (ie modify `exception_coroutine`). But I cannot change several of the intermediate methods.

Is there something I can do in order to *force* the exception to be raised throughout the Tornado stack, even if it is not properly yielded? Basically to properly raise the exception in all of the last three situations?

This is complicated because I **cannot** change the code that is causing this situation. I can only change `exception_coroutine` for example in the above.

Comment: Two questions. First, can you give an example or a sketch of the calling code? I'm having some trouble understanding your intent. Second, do you want the caller to *block* until the coroutine completes (either normally or by raising an exception)?

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis the above stubbed functions reflect how this is being called. Regarding 2, see my edit - I want to see the exception in my try/except.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is impossible in Python because the decision to `yield` or not is made by the calling function after the coroutine has finished. The coroutine must return without raising an exception so it can be `yielded`, and after that it is no longer possible for it to raise an exception into the caller's context in the event that the `Future` is not `yielded`.

The best you can do is detect the garbage collection of a Future, but this can't do anything but log (this is how the "future exception not retrieved" message works)

Answer (score -1):

If you're curious why this isn't working, it's because no_coroutine_create_exception contains a yield statement. Therefore it's a generator function, and calling it does *not* execute its code, it only creates a generator object:

```
>>> no_coroutine_create_exception(True)
<generator object no_coroutine_create_exception at 0x101651678>
>>> no_coroutine_create_exception(False)
<generator object no_coroutine_create_exception at 0x1016516d0>
```

Neither of the calls above executes any Python code, it only creates generators that must be iterated.

You'd have to make a blocking function that starts the IOLoop and runs it until your coroutine finishes:

```
def exception_blocking():
    return ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(exception_coroutine)


exception_blocking()
```

(The IOLoop acts as a scheduler for multiple non-blocking tasks, and the `gen.coroutine` decorator is responsible for iterating the coroutine until completion.)

However, I think I'm likely answering your immediate question but merely enabling you to proceed down an unproductive path. You're almost certainly better off using async code or blocking code throughout instead of trying to mix them.

Comment: I cannot change the underlying call structure (I thought this was clear in the question?), so while this is well intentioned, it does not help.